# Problems with the float datatype in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a column with default `float` datatype.

Now, when I insert a number such as `12345678`, the value is stored as `12345700` in that column.

Is this something to do with the precision?

Can someone please explain me what is happening here?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is because of precision. A float data type has at most 7 significant figures of precision. This is not just MySQL specific, it applies to all strongly typed programming languages and most software written in those languages.

Answer (score -1):

By default [`FLOAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/floating-point-types.html) is a stored as a 4-byte single-precision value. It has 24-bits of significant data.

If you expect bigger numbers use either `DOUBLE` (stored in 8-bytes) or better yet, use `DECIMAL`.